# Surface plot without interpolation

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matrix `Z` that is *`n`*-by-*`m`*. I also have vector `x` of size `n` and vector `y` of size `m`.

If I use simply `imagesc(Z)`, I see what I want to see (small rectangles for each component), but the axes do not correspond to `x` and `y`.

If I use

```
[XX,YY]=meshrid(x,y)

surf(XX,YY,Z)
view(0,90)
```

the axes are good, but the picture is somewhat fuzzy. Is it possible to use `surf` without interpolation, just having a fixed value for a constant rectangular area? Is it possible to use `imagesc` with specification of `x` and `y` axes?

Comment: Why not just interpolate though? It's not difficult...

Comment: [`imagesc(x,y,Z)`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html)

Comment: `[X,Y,Z] = peaks; surf(X, Y, Z); view(0,90); shading flat`